# replace rule below title with box

Tags: titles, boxes

I'd like to change the rule above and below the title in this document, instead putting the title, author and date information inside a (hopefully stylish looking) box. Any help appreciated!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{hitec}
\author{Ms Anonymous}
\date{February 14, 2016}
\title{Title of the document}


\begin{document}
\maketitle


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `\@maketitle` in `hitec.cls` or redefine it in the preamble. Example:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{hitec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
  \def\@maketitle{%
    \newpage
    \null
\leavevmode\setbox0=\lastbox
\hspace{-\leftmarginwidth}    
{\fboxsep2em\fboxrule3pt
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\fullwidth-4em-6pt}
{\Large\bfseries \@title \par}
\raggedleft
{\slshape\@author\@tcompany\par}
\vskip 1em%
{\@date}%
\end{minipage}}}}%
\makeatother

\author{Ms Anonymous}
\date{February 14, 2016}
\title{Title of the document}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Lore ipsum}\lipsum[1]
\section{Nam dui ligula}\lipsum[2]
\section{Nulla malesuada}\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```